# statistics on question types

Tags: discussion

I have been here long enough to recognize that most of the questions posted here fall into a short list of different classes. examples: obvious homework or exam questions, high-level mathematical physics enquiries, crank/goofball stuff, everyday physics, off-topic (engineering, electronics, etc.). I'm curious- has anyone here tabulated any statistical data on the frequency with which different classes of questions get posted- and answered- here? best regards, niels

Comment: I think the main obstacle to this is classifying the questions. If you can offer an automated way to do this, it shouldn't be hard to get the results you want. (And you can even do it yourself using the data dump or [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com).)

Comment: Agree. I can take a stab at it manually, using a month's worth of questions, and if I get anything of interest I will post here.